# OSMnx and NetworkX: How to find total length and travel_time for the same path?

Tags: networkx, osmnx

I am using NetworkX version 3.1 and OSMnx version 1.5.1

I am sharing this information for anyone who may find this useful.

I obtain a road driving graph from OpenStreetMap using OSMnx, and have been finding travel distance and travel time using the function shortest_path_length() like this:

> route_travel_time = nx.shortest_path_length(route_graph, start_node,
> destination_node, weight='travel_time') *# This works, and returns the time in seconds*
>
> route_length = nx.shortest_path_length(route_graph,
> start_node, destination_node, weight='length') *# Also works and
> returns the distance in meters*

However, in some cases, due to the road network, there are two or more different paths, one faster and the other shorter, and the shortest_path_length function then returns the faster time and the shorter length, **even though they are from different paths**!  This is not what I want in my application.

I decided that I want to pick the shortest path by length and then I want to find the time associated with that particular path.

I simply could not get this to work properly using NetworkX's own documentation.  Finally, through much trial and error:

First, I just get the shortest path by length using this code which works:

`route = nx.shortest_path(route_graph, start_node, destination_node, weight='length') *# Returns a list of nodes comprising the route`

Then I loop through all the edges of the graph which match the shortest path list of nodes.

```
route_length_exp = route_travel_time_exp = 0

for u, v in zip(route, route[1:]):  
 edge_length = route_graph.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['length']   # Returns length in meters, e.g. 50.26
 route_length_exp += edge_length
 edge_travel_time = route_graph.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['travel_time'] # Returns travel time in secs
 route_travel_time_exp += edge_travel_time
```

The magic is in the expression `route_graph.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['travel_time']`.

I struggled for a long time and the many NetworkX expressions that I found in the documentation and elsewhere threw exceptions about being unsubscriptable.  I don't claim to understand this fully, but it worked for me.

I am interested in different solutions that are more elegant or have better performance.  Please state your NetworkX and OSMnx versions when you do!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use OSMnx's [route_to_gdf](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#osmnx.utils_graph.route_to_gdf) function. This uses the latest relase of OSMnx as of today (v1.6.0) and avoids any direct calls to NetworkX. Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place("Piedmont, CA, USA", network_type="drive")
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(ox.add_edge_speeds(G))

# first solve a shortest path by travel time
weight = "travel_time"
route = ox.shortest_path(G, list(G.nodes)[0], list(G.nodes)[9], weight)

# then find the length of that path
gdf = ox.utils_graph.route_to_gdf(G, route, weight)
gdf["length"].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach for computing `route_travel_time_exp` is correct. but there are so many missing values for the `travel_time` attribute. why?
`travel_time` attribute, computed based on the maxspeed attribute of edges. but many of the OSM edge data don't have the maxspeed attribute (OSM is open-source). So Before running the for loop, you should make sure that all edges have the `travel_time` attribute. The `osmnx` provides a [method](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-reference.html#osmnx.speed.add_edge_travel_times) to add travel time to the edge features. But consider that (from `osmnx` documentation):

> By default, this imputes free-flow travel speeds for all edges via the mean maxspeed value of the edges of each highway type. For highway types in the graph that have no maxspeed value on any edge, it assigns the mean of all maxspeed values in graph.
>
> This default mean-imputation can obviously be imprecise, and the user
> can override it by passing in hwy_speeds and/or fallback arguments
> that correspond to local speed limit standards. The user can also
> specify a different aggregation function (such as the median) to
> impute missing values from the observed values.

So adding the following codes before the for loop helps the code run. but to have higher precision, use the `add_edge_speeds` method with appropriate arguments.

```
import osmnx as ox
route_graph = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(route_graph)
route_graph = ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(route_graph)
```

So the full version of the code should be:

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

# get original network
route_graph = ox.graph_from_place("Aachen, Germany", network_type="drive")

route_graph = ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(route_graph)
route_graph = ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(route_graph)

# set start and end nodes
start_node = 2291336
end_node = 267950285

route = nx.shortest_path(route_graph, start_node, end_node, weight='length') # Returns a list of nodes comprising the route

route_length_exp = route_travel_time_exp = 0

for u, v in zip(route, route[1:]):  
    edge_length = route_graph.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['length']   # Returns length in meters, e.g. 50.26
    route_length_exp += edge_length
    edge_travel_time = route_graph.get_edge_data(u,v)[0]['travel_time'] # Returns travel time in secs
    route_travel_time_exp += edge_travel_time
```